# Clear Excel Sheet Formatting through VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, formatting, excel-2010

I need to clear all of the formatting for an entire excel workbook I'm working with. I know using VBA I can clear the workbook of all formatting by writing:

```
Cells.Select
Selection.ClearFormats
```

What is the VB.NET equivalent of the aforementioned VBA code?

Comment: Are you using interop? - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.clearformats.aspx

Comment: No, but should I be using it? Would that allow me to use VBA code?

Comment: It depends.... Interop has A LOT of limitations, but it also can be useful (namely, the object model for code is near identical to VBA)... The bigger question is what are you using to create / edit the excel data??

Comment: So far I've just been taking data from an excel file and putting it into a SQL table using a sqlbulk command. I'm selecting the data from the excel sheets using an oledbdataadapter.

Comment: So, up until now, you  haven't had to deal with Excel itself... Now that you're into manipulating Excel ibjects, you're going to have to look into libraries for Excel file manipulation... There are plenty of resources online discussing how this is done in .Net - Each will have its strengths and weaknesses... Interop can be a good choice with a smaller learning curve, but has a lot of weaknesses. Another good one that's free is EpPlus... Then there are plenty of others.

Comment: Thanks, John Bustos. Interop has done the trick. You were right about the object model for the code being very similar to VBA. To clear my worksheet (ws) of all formatting I just used the following statement.

ws.Cells.ClearFormats()

Comment: Glad it worked! - FYI since you're new to Stack overflow, I'd suggest just writing a quick explanation of what worked for you as a solution and then marking this question as resolved... It'll show others that have the same issue what worked for you and it'll help your ranking with the site...